# Access the assets list through GEE API

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I'm using the Python GEE API.
I'm able to crawl in my tasks through this :

```py
 #search for the task in task_list
    filename = construct_filename(country_code, year)
    tasks_list = ee.batch.Task.list()
    current_task = ''
    for task in tasks_list:
        if task.config['description'] == filename:
            current_task = task
            break
```

Is it possible to do the same in my Assets and if yes how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be Adapted to your needs but there is an undocumented function in Gee API that works just fine :

```py
import ee

ee.Initialize()

#retreive the user folder name
folder = ee.data.getAssetRoots()[0]['id']  #maybe not the most elegant way
assets = ee.data.listAssets({'parent': folder})
```

and you'll be able to crawl in the `assets` variable

Answer (score 1):

```
import ee
ee.Initialize()

folder = ee.data.getAssetRoots()
file_list = []
for file in folder:
    file_list.append(file['id'])
```

Comment: I think your answer is listing the available folder/projects and not the assets stored inside them. When testing from my side I get only my projects.